# How can I add one enchant level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to with every command add one enchantment level like this:

```
/replaceitem entity {player} slot.armor.head chainmail_helmet 1 0 {ench:[{id:0,lvl:+1}]
```

Level: **+1**

**Or**

If I have a helmet with protection: 1, after the command it should be protection: 2.

Can you help me?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, you can only list out all the enchantment you want with level, detect the current enchantment and give 1 more level...

Answer (score 1):

you can do it, but it will need multiple command blocks, first of all, you will use testfor for example

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",Damage:0s,Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:20s,lvl:1s}]}}}
```

that's if you want it for an item, but if you want it for a piece of armor try this

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:chainmail_chestplate",Damage:0s,Count:1b,Slot:102s,tag:{ench:[{id:4s,lvl:1s}]}}]}
```

after using the testfor in a repeat command block that is always active and nonconditional then put in front of it a chain command block that is **conditional and always active** and then write inside of it

```
/replaceitem entity @a slot.armor.chest minecraft:chainmail_chestplate 1 0 {ench:[{id:4s,lvl:2s}]}
```

and if it had level 2 repeat the steps mentioned up, just replace the first command(for the armor) enchantment from 1 to X(the level you want) and the second command from 2 to X+1

Comment: You should **not** be using `@e`, which selects **all** entities. As the question and data refer to players only, you should be using `@a`. Secondly, be aware that this is **not** multiplayer-friendly. The `/replaceitem` command presented is going to affect all players, not the relevant ones. If only one player matched, then all players are modified. You should be using `/scoreboard` to assign a label (score or "tag") instead of using `/testfor`, which is mostly useless for multiplayer-friendliness.

Comment: you are right, sorry, do I edit my answer or add a new one?

Comment: Editing is fine!

Comment: edited the post, done ;)

Answer (score -1):

wel idk if this helps but this is the command for 1.14.4 `/replaceitem entity @p armor.head chainmail_helmet{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:1}]}`

Comment: How is this supposed to increase the enchantment level each time the command is run? Your solution does not accomplish the asker's request.